# Billdesk payment gateway integration in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, payment-gateway

I'm planning to integrate billdesk payment gateway in one of our magento projects does billdesk provide any module to integrate it?
We donot have much time to build it, are there any free modules?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try installing this free extension. I have tried it in one of our projects. It seems to work fine.
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/31935/s/billdesk-payment-gateway-extension/

[Click here for extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/31935/s/billdesk-payment-gateway-extension/)

Comment: I want to integrade billdesk retun APi with magento how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the only relevant result I could find on Google: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/billdesk-payment-gateway.html

Please let me know if that's not what you're looking for, I'll deleted my answer

Comment: I want to integrade billdesk retun APi with magento how to do that ?